# CALayer CABasicAnimation opacity

Tags: swift3, calayer

I've created an animation but I can´t make work the duration property.

```
let animationFadeOut = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
animationFadeOut.fromValue = 1
animationFadeOut.toValue = 0
animationFadeOut.duration = 1
imageViewDos.layer?.add(animationFadeOut, forKey: nil)
```

No matter what value I put, it always has the same duration.

Comment: you have set values for animationFadeOut and you are using animationFadeIn

Comment: I've made both animations, FadeIn and FadeOut. It's an error pasting. Updated. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fromValue` and `toValue` need to be defined as `NSNumbers`

```
animationFadeOut.fromValue = NSNumber(floatLiteral: 1)
animationFadeOut.toValue = NSNumber(floatLiteral: 0)
```